# Criteria on values taken into consideration in a MYSQL MIN/Max/Avg calculation

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the MIN/MAX/AVG from my database, but there may be some spurious results from time to time. Basically, I only want MYSQL to give me the minimum etc of a difference calculation.

The criteria I need would be +65.00 each way.

**Here is some sample data**

```
Actual  
1854  
1843
1865
1822
1833
1859
1400
```

**Here is my query -**

```
Select MIN(ACTUAL - 1800), MAX(ACTUAL - 1800), AVG(ACTUAL - 1800) FROM ACTUAL_TABLE WHERE DATE = '2015-08-09'
```

**This query result would be -**

```
MIN     MAX  AVG
-400    65  -17.71428571
```

So clearly, the query is picking up the 1400 in the actual table, and the difference is -400, I need it to ignore this result as its past the > -65.00 criteria I need.

**If the criteria was in place the result would look like this -**

```
MIN     MAX  AVG
22  65  -17.71428571
```

I have tried putting a CASE in the SQL and had no joy. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only the values you want

```
Select MIN(ACTUAL - 1800), MAX(ACTUAL - 1800), AVG(ACTUAL - 1800) 
   FROM ACTUAL_TABLE 
   WHERE DATE = '2015-08-09' AND ACTUAL >= (1800-65) AND ACTUAL <= (1800+65);
```